# Check if function is complete in function that is triggered by unrelated event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called call facebook.

```
call_facebook(284328420994");
call_facebook(197214710347172);
```

It runs severaltimes It makes an ajax request to facebook and often takes a few seconds to complete.

I have an other function that modifies the html when I click a marker on a google map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(loc, 'click', function () {
    var template = $('#trips').html();
    var content = locationIndex[loc.title];
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template,  content );
});
```

If one of the markers are clicked and then a call_facebook-event is completed. I want to rerun the function that get's triggered when you click the marker. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a callback that your `call_facebook` function checks from the ajax success callback. If there's no callback listed on it, do nothing; if there is, run it. Combine that with a flag telling you whether there's an outstanding `call_facebook` call and you can check that from your `click` handler. *Something* like this:

```
var done_callbacks = [];
var activecalls = 0;
function call_facebook(id) {
    // Set active flag
    ++activecalls;

    // Start ajax
    start_ajax_call(/* ... */, function() {
        var f;

        // This is the "success" callback

        // Decrement active flag
        --activecalls;
        if (activecalls === 0) {
            // None others are active, process callbacks
            while (done_callbacks.length !== 0) {
               f = done_callbacks.shift();
               f();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then

```
google.maps.event.addListener(loc, 'click', function () {

    if (activecalls === 0) {
        doUpdate();
    }
    else {
        done_callbacks.push(doUpdate);
    }

    function doUpdate() {
        var template = $('#trips').html();
        var content = locationIndex[loc.title];
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template,  content );
    }
});
```

There are various improvements you could make to the above. If for instance, you only need to hook together two things related to the same `loc`, you could use a map of callbacks rather than an array and only fire the relevant one. You could isolate the logic in the `click` handler into another function alongside `call_facebook` (for maintenance), etc., etc. You might trap errors around the `f();` call. But that's the basic idea.

Note that there is no race condition above, even though it can see as though there is. Events are asynchronous and can be *queued* at any time, including when JavaScript code is running; but their handlers will never run simultaneously because unless you use web workers (which we aren't above), JavaScript on the browser is single-threaded. So we won't (for instance) check `activecalls === 0` in the `click` handler and then have it change before the next statement in the `click` handler executes.

Comment: This works nicely(apart from a spellingerror and the wrong name of a variable), I was planning on updating the content every time a call_facebook-call was completed, but I'll get that working!